Neural Network not targeting any particular output but using backpropagation to shapes input
I don't know if that exists or how is that called, but can I make a Neural Network to adapt directly the input from an error function?
Assume I have 2 complex(I mean hard to compute, domain still in real numbers) polynomials with 5 shared parameters(including x) and I want to find the the combinations of parameters that minimize the 2 polynomials(some minimum squared sum assuming the parameters assume same value for both polynomials)to the best extent possible (so actually maybe they are both 0 for some combination of parameters, but maybe the smallest value they can have at same time is 3 and 4 and the squared minimum sum is therefore 9+16=25)
In example

30ax+bx-4cx^2+dx^7
2ax^7-bx^2+cx-6dx^9

Where a,b,c,d,x are the parameters.
Try to forget there are math ways to find the answer and also algorithms for that. I want to use a Neural Network.
I therefore have a neural network with 5 inputs and 2 outputs. (As many hidden layer and neurons as needed)
Is it possibile to put the p1(x) and p2(x) values(or a fraction of that) polynomials value computed for the given parameters in the output and use that directly as delta for backpropagation in order to find a combination of parameters near the real minimum?
So I put random parameters. Then enter a loop where parameters compute the polynomials value, then use that value as error, backpropagate it to adjust the parameters in a loop until I find a local minimum (optional, if possible a global minimum, or something near, I guest I should try different sets of random initial parameters in theory right?)
** Note minimizing the squared sum means going
towards Y=0 so probably I have to change the sign of the output to make sure It goes to right direction
